# Delete all triples about event time except earliest event time

Tags: sparql, rdf

I have several triples like this

```
:event1 :hasTimeStamp "2017-06-30T00:01:00Z" .
:event1 :hasTimeStamp "2017-06-30T00:02:00Z" .
:event1 :hasTimeStamp "2017-06-30T00:03:00Z" .
```

I would like to delete all of the assertions about `:event1`'s `timestamp` except the earliest.

I know how to select the earliest, insert it into a scratch named graph, delete all `:event1` `timestamp`s, and then copy back from the scratch graph.

Is there a way to do the deletion in place, with no utilization of a temporary/scratch graph?

Here's a nested select, where the inner subselect gets the minimum time, which is then be compared with the individual times form the outer select.

Now I just have to wrap that in the `delete`.

```
PREFIX  rdf:  <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
SELECT  *
WHERE
  { ?s        rdf:type              <http://turbo.org/procStartTimeMeas> ;
              <http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/IAO_0000136>  ?something .
    ?something  <http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/RO_0002223>  ?another .
    ?another  rdf:type              <http://turbo.org/R2RInstantiation> .
    ?s        <http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/IAO_0000004>  ?o
    { SELECT  ?s (MIN(?o) AS ?earliest)
      WHERE
        { ?s        rdf:type              <http://turbo.org/procStartTimeMeas> ;
                    <http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/IAO_0000136>  ?something .
          ?something  <http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/RO_0002223>  ?another .
          ?another  rdf:type              <http://turbo.org/R2RInstantiation> .
          ?s        <http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/IAO_0000004>  ?o
        }
      GROUP BY ?s
    }
    FILTER ( ?o != ?earliest )
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this (not in the production environment):

```sql
PREFIX  rdf:  <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>

DELETE {
  ?s <http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/IAO_0000004> ?o2 .
}
WHERE { 
  ?s <http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/IAO_0000004> ?o2 .
  ?s rdf:type <http://turbo.org/procStartTimeMeas> .
  FILTER EXISTS {
  ?s <http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/IAO_0000004> ?o1 .
  ?s rdf:type <http://turbo.org/procStartTimeMeas> .
  FILTER (?o2 > ?o1)
  }   
}
```

I'm not sure I understand correctly what these predicates mean.

I suppose `<http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/IAO_0000004>` is `:hasTimeStamp` of the initial example.
In my answer, `?s rdf:type <http://turbo.org/procStartTimeMeas>` is the only selection criterion. Please add other criteria.

Comment: Thanks.  I haven't tested this, but I think I see what you mean.  I certainly didn't expect anybody to rewrite all of the triple patterns.

Comment: BTW, can you think of any advantages or disadvantages of your `FILTER EXISTS` approach vs. my subquery?

Comment: @MarkMiller, I just can't understand your query (though most likely it is correct). Partly because I'm not familiar with the obolibrary.org and turbo.org ontologies, but also your query is long. As to performance consideration, one should test or look at execution plans… Perhaps, SPARQL algebra representation of respective SELECT queries would be useful.

Comment: Only 5 people on earth are familiar with the turbo ontology at this point in time!

Comment: Ignoring the fact that I have more constraints in my triple patterns, this method does seem to do the desired deletion.

Answer (score 3):

(An alternative to the nice solution of @StansilavKralin)

I just did it based on the sample data

```
@prefix : <http://example.org/> .
@prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
:event1 :hasTimeStamp "2017-06-30T00:01:00Z"^^xsd:dateTime .
:event1 :hasTimeStamp "2017-06-30T00:02:00Z"^^xsd:dateTime .
:event1 :hasTimeStamp "2017-06-30T00:03:00Z"^^xsd:dateTime .
```

Not sure whether this is what you want, but at least it's pretty compact and I'm a big fan of [`MINUS`](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#neg-minus) which is at least more human readable (but maybe less performant):

```sql
PREFIX : <http://example.org/>
DELETE {
  ?event :hasTimeStamp ?ts .
}
WHERE
  { ?event  :hasTimeStamp  ?ts
    MINUS
      { { SELECT  ?event (MIN(?_ts) AS ?ts)
          WHERE
            { ?event  :hasTimeStamp  ?_ts }
          GROUP BY ?event
        }
      }
  }
```

Comment: thanks... bad timing.  i just accepted @Stanislav's answer.  i'll try yours now and let you know.

Comment: that works too.  it's not any slower than the others.

Comment: No worries, I just wanted to try it out anyways. Thank's for letting me know that it works. I guess it's more the SQL way that I used here where `MINUS` is more common than the pretty neat `EXISTS` feature of SPARQL. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I think this does what I want, but I'd like to see suggestions from others. I don't want to be reckless with a deletion.

```
PREFIX  rdf:  <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
DELETE {
  ?s <http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/IAO_0000004> ?o .
}
WHERE
  { SELECT  *
    WHERE
      { ?s        rdf:type              <http://turbo.org/procStartTimeMeas> ;
                  <http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/IAO_0000136>  ?something .
        ?something  <http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/RO_0002223>  ?another .
        ?another  rdf:type              <http://turbo.org/R2RInstantiation> .
        ?s        <http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/IAO_0000004>  ?o
        { SELECT  ?s (MIN(?o) AS ?earliest)
          WHERE
            { ?s        rdf:type              <http://turbo.org/procStartTimeMeas> ;
                        <http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/IAO_0000136>  ?something .
              ?something  <http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/RO_0002223>  ?another .
              ?another  rdf:type              <http://turbo.org/R2RInstantiation> .
              ?s        <http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/IAO_0000004>  ?o
            }
          GROUP BY ?s
        }
        FILTER ( ?o != ?earliest )
      }
  }
```